# global definition of a variable in C

Tags: c, global-variables

In simple terms global variables are variables that are declared or defined outside main() and has scope from the point of definition to the end of the program.

I have a few questions on global variables. I am using GCC compiler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a,b;
a=b=1;
main()
{
     printf("%d\n%d",a,b);
}
```

This program generates error while

```
#include<stdio.h>
int a,b;

main()
{
     a=b=1;
     printf("%d\n%d",a,b);
}
```

generates the correct output.Why a=b=1 is not supported when used globally?

I have one more question to ask.

```
#include<stdio.h>
a=1;
b=9;
c='c';
h='h';

main()
{
    printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
    printf("%c\t%c\n",c,h);

}
```

produces the correct result with warning that data definition has no type or storage class.  I am totally confused with global variables.

Comment: in last one its a warning bcoz ur main function has no return type.

Comment: @Vimal: This simply is wrong.

Comment: i ran that code with a return type and without return type.. and ofcourse u need to declare data type for global variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
a=b=1;
```

is a *statement*, and in the global scope you can't have statements, only declarations and definitions.

When you do

```
a=1;
```

you implicitly define the variable `a` as an `int` and then *initialize* it to the value `1`. This can only be done in the global scope, but don't do it as it's going to cause a lot of confusion.